# how to build component render multiple rows inside a table in React or Vue

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Just wonder if I build component to render partial of the table rows, how should I do that?

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <partialrows :data="dataset1" />
      <partialrows :data="dataset2" />
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want each partialrows to render couple rows

```
<tr><td colspan=2>title ds 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>ds01</td><td>ds02</td></tr>
<tr><td>ds11</td><td>ds12</td></tr>
<tr><td>ds21</td><td>ds22</td></tr>
```

But this violate single root element rule, I wonder how to solve this in either React or Vue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, you could use a [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) or [vue-fragments](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment). Have a look at [this article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/09/11/vue-multiple-root-fragments/).

In React, there are [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Vue now, that is so sad there is no official Component for that. But Thanks so much, this helps a lot

Comment: Look for "Functional components with render functions" in https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/09/11/vue-multiple-root-fragments/. He does pretty much exactly what you are looking for in Vue using a (standard) functional component.